# Strange publish date in django

Tags: django

I have a publish date for blog posts in my model like this:

```
    published=models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="date published")
```

Then somewhere in my templates, I have this:

```
    {{ post.published }}
    {{ post.published.day }}
```

And the output becomes this:

```
    November 29, 2017
    28
```

So why the second line shows **one day earlier**???

PS: It wasn't like this last week, but I don't know what I have changed since then. I don't use version control!

Comment: how about `{{ post.published.date }}`, it that same? I think you should setup `TIME_ZONE` in you `settings.py` wich your current location.

Comment: That shows 28th and Time_Zone is ok.